# Q: How to make a where with two fields in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

if I have two fields ( let's say field1 and field2 )

How to make this Query in Eloquent ?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field1` < `field2`;
```

`$query->where('field1','<','field2')`

doesn't work. Backticks doesn't work either ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query->whereRaw('field1 < field2');
```

Comment: ty ... this works perfect! ... Sometimes there are too many trees in the forest ^^

Answer (score 0):

According to [laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('field1', '<', 'field2')
                ->get();
```

in Eloquent

```
$users = User::where('field1', '<', 'field2')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: I prefer Eloquent for Models ... DB:: is not suitable in this case. Sorry for missunderstanding expain ...

Comment: dear, you can easily convert this query to eloquent, just look at the docs. See my updated answer.

Comment: your Eqloquent-answer would _not_ work ... this was the matter to ask this question. field2 must be an value and could not be a field ...